# How to install PHP, Pear, PECL, and APC with Homebrew on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, php, homebrew, pecl, php-apc

I'm trying to install APC for PHP 5.3 in the easiest way possible. I love [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) so I started down that route. I was able to install PHP 5.3.6 with this command:

```
brew install https://github.com/adamv/homebrew-alt/raw/master/duplicates/php.rb --with-mysql
```

I think this is supposed to install PHP, Pear, and PECL. It seems to install these just fine.

Now when I try to install APC:

```
$ pecl install apc
downloading APC-3.1.9.tgz ...
Starting to download APC-3.1.9.tgz (155,540 bytes)
.................................done: 155,540 bytes

Warning: require_once(Archive/Tar.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in PackageFile.php on line 305

Warning: require_once(Archive/Tar.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/Cellar/php/5.3.6/lib/php/PEAR/PackageFile.php on line 305

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Archive/Tar.php' (include_path='/usr/local/Cellar/php/5.3.6/lib/php') in /usr/local/Cellar/php/5.3.6/lib/php/PEAR/PackageFile.php on line 305
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 17):

Now [`homebrew-php`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php) has been migrated to [`homebrew-core`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core) and by default, PECL should be installed along with your PHP.

Here are the suggested steps:

1. Reinstall PHP via: `brew install php`.
2. Check `pecl` command by: `which -a pecl`.

To see which files were installed, see: `brew list php`.

To install PHP extensions, you need to use PECL as a recommended way.

> With the migration to Homebrew-core the php formula has stopped taking over the role of PECL. Installing xdebug can (and should) be done through PECL. Source: [GH-26007](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/26007#issuecomment-377715665)

For example: `pecl install apc` or `pecl install xdebug`.

If you've got some problem installing the extension, you need to report it to its maintainer. Check [PECL website](https://pecl.php.net/) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

`pecl` and `pear` are provided with Homebrew's version of PHP:

```
brew install php
pecl install apcu
```

If you're weary that `pecl` and `pear` are provided by php, try this:

```
ls -al $(which pecl)
ls -al $(which pear)
```

Both locations should symlink to `Cellar/php/...`

Note, macOS provides a php version which is generally behind that of Homebrew.  To make sure you're running the Homebrew version, prefix your `php` commands with `$(brew --prefix php)/bin`.

Example for Composer:

```
$(brew --prefix php)/bin/php composer.phar install
```

The reason this is important is because common extensions -- such as `ext-intl` and `ext-gettext` are provided automatically and will fix these automatically.

Notice, for `php-fpm`, use `brew reinstall php --with-fpm`.  The `php-fpm` path will be... `$(brew --prefix php)/sbin/php-fpm`.

Answer (score 2):

Below command should help

```
curl -s -O https://pear.php.net/install-pear-nozlib.phar

sudo php install-pear-nozlib.phar -d /usr/local/lib/php -b /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

[Homebrew PHP's GitHub site says that:](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php#pear-extensions)

> Pear is no longer compiled by default, instead you need to install php with the --with-pear option, such as: brew install php56 --with-pear.

So, to make PHP 7.0 work, use the following installation command:

`brew install php70 --with-pear`

You can of course use this with other versions of PHP, too.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need install `apc`.
Just add

```
apc.enabled=on
apc.shm_size=64M
apc.enable_cli=on
```

to your `php.ini` and make sure that your apcu is ok.